# mysql with php, session multi level users authentication and pages

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am trying to implement my own class, functions and views to implement multi-user authentication and pages with php, mysql and pdo class.

Please let me know if I am doing it in proper way or I am on wrong path?

**Mysql table will look like:**

```
userID-----------int              1
userName---------varchar          abc
userPassword-----varchar          pass
userAccessCode---int              100
```

This is the html, and php which will pass the data via post to function called(***aut***) in class authen

**note: session will be start in header login. and close on logout**

```
      //include authen class
      if(isset(POST){
            $authen->name= Check_Params($_POST['name ']);
            $authen->pass= Check_Params($_POST['pass']);
            $authen->accs= Check_Params($_POST['accs']);
            $authen->aut()
       }

    <form method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <input name="pass" type="password">
    <input name="access" type="password">
    <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
```

Now authen class will check if the user is in database:

```
public function auth() {
        $name = Check_Param($this->name);
        $pass = Check_Param($this->pass);
        $accs = Check_Param($this->accs);
        $passhashed = hash_pass(Check_Params($this->password));
        $stm = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userTBL WHERE `userName`=:name AND `userPassword`=:pass AND `userAccessCode`=:accs LIMIT 1";
        $stm = $this->conn->prepare($stmt9);
        $stm->bindParam(':nameo', $name);
        $stm->bindParam(':passs', $passhashed);
        $stm->bindParam(':accs', $accs);
        $stm->execute();
        $checkstm = $stm->fetchColumn();   
        if ($checkstm == 1) {  
            $_SESSION['accs'] = Check_Params($accs);
            $_SESSION['name'] = Check_Params($name);
            header("location:../home");
            exit;
        } else {
            header("location:logout.php");
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Now in each page this will check if it's login request, here is the **ifitislogin** function

```
public function ifitislogin() {
        if ($_SESSION['name'] == '' | $_SESSION['accs'] == '') {
            header("location:logout.php");
        } else {
            $accs = Check_Params(preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["accs"]));
            $name = Check_Params(preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["name"]));
            $stm = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userTBL WHERE `userName`=:name AND `userAccessCode`=:accs";
            stm = $this->conn->prepare($stmt9);
            $stm->bindParam(':nameo', $name);
            $stm->bindParam(':accs', $accs);
            $stm->execute();
            $checkstm = $stm->fetchColumn();
            if ($checkstm != 1) {
                header("location:logout.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now for example this is the index page for all:

```
//include class authentic
    $authen->ifitislogin();   // this will check if user is valid:



    echo "<h1>" welcome to the document management system</h1> <br/>";

    //this will befor admin and operator 
    if($_SESSION['accs'] = Check_Params('100')){
            echo "<h1>welcome to admin page data....</h1>";
    } elseif($_SESSION['accs']) == 101) {
           echo "<h1>welcome to reporter page data....</h1>"
    } else {
            echo "welcome msg";
    }

    //this will be for clients or users, the function will get the result from database based on the user name and accs/        
    $accs = Check_Params($_SESSION['accs']);
    $name = Check_Params($_SESSION['name']);   
    //get the result from database based on these tow variable which means $accs, $name it will select from database base where access = $accs and name = $name
```

In this code section querying the data from database based on the data i get from session variables is it ok? if not how can i know which data should display to which user? or which page is for which user?

regards in advances.

Comment: Make a two pages one page which will be only show to register users and one which will be show who are not members of your page.

Comment: i dont mean to register any user, it's only user accessible web-app, here am i doing the session management correct or not it it secure, i am using ssl too